# Bootstrap is baffling me : <nav> , .nav, .navbar-nav, .navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap. Every time I create navigation bars with Bootstrap, I am using these elements/classes, but all of these confuse me:

```
<nav> 
.nav
.navbar
.navbar-nav
```

Can anyone please explain the difference between those elements/classes?

Answer (score 1):

There's a good explanation in [Bootstraps v4 documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/) (I just c/p the required parts).

[Navbar](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#basics):

> Navbars require a wrapping `.navbar` and a color scheme.
>
> Ensure accessibility by using a `<nav>` element or, if using a more generic element such as a `<div>`, add a `role="navigation"` to every navbar to explicitly identify it as a landmark region for users of assistive technologies
>
> `.navbar-nav` for a full-height and lightweight navigation (including support for dropdowns)

[Navs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#base-nav):

> Roll your own navigation style by extending the base `.nav` component. All Bootstrap’s nav components are built on top of this by specifying additional styles. Includes styles for the disabled state, but not the active state.

Answer (score 0):

The `<nav>` tag is not styled by bootstrap, it is just a HTML5 tag indicating the navigation. The other classes are used to style different parts of the Bootstrap navbar-component. What exactly each of these classes do can be seen using the developer-tools of any browser. Right click your finished navbar and select 'inspect element' or something similar and navigate through the DOM.

The reason for all of these classes is that Bootstrap tries to make their components more reusable. If it would style all `nav`-elements as its navbar-component it would make it difficult for developers to create their own navbars because they would need to override any Bootstrap-styles on this element.

Answer (score 0):

These are the bootstrap classes which perform specific function which user wants to implement. In your case you want to add a navbar to a page and uses bootstrap navbar class to implement the functionality. If you see the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js file source code and find the navbar class, you can see the code of navbar class.
This is the code snippet from source file.

```
  .navbar-nav {
  margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

if you use this navbar-nav class. This functionality will be added to your element.